# How to add all tables from selected Personal geodatabase

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I have a personal geodatabase which contains multiple tables and feature classes which are within feature datasets. I can add all the feature classes to ArcMap but I am unable to add all tables. Can anyone help me?

I just **want to add all tables from personalGDB to ArcMap** in single click

[image]

Comment: You have tagged this question with ArcObjects, what is your existing code? Please amend your question.